# Microsoft Outlook Add-ins: Which Add-in mode to chose for a new Add-in development?

Tags: outlook, office365, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

There are two variants of Outlook Add-ins

1. Add-ins that open on the right(task pane add-ins) (Ex: [Salesforce Add-in](https://store.office.com/en-us/app.aspx?assetid=WA104379334&sourcecorrid=df2a177e-a07a-4a37-b22c-259c7b3b2a0b&searchapppos=0&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&appredirect=false))
2. Add-ins that open above the message in readmode( Ex:[Teamviewer](https://store.office.com/en-us/app.aspx?assetid=WA104379426&sourcecorrid=7ef103eb-5ecb-46a9-90f2-106f5e33ed28&searchapppos=0&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&appredirect=false))

How does one decide which approach to take for a new Add-in development. Are there any suggested guidelines?

Comment: You should start with the list of features your addin must implement, then figure out the right API for the job ( JS addin vs COM addin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Salesforce add-In you linked uses the preferred model for add-ins: [add-in commands](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/outlook/add-in-commands-for-outlook). They add a button to the ribbon, and that ribbon opens the taskpane. Under this model there is no "grey bar" and no opening above the message. Note that add-in commands can also invoke actions with no UI (in other words, you don't have to open a taskpane).

The Teamviewer add-in you linked uses the old add-in model, which is deemphasized. New add-ins should definitely NOT use this model, unless you're developing something for internal use at your company on on-premises Exchange servers that don't support add-in commands.

Answer (score 0):

Use add-in commands. Add-ins that don't use commands are no longer allowed on the Office Store. See [post](https://dev.office.com/blogs/make-your-add-ins-available-in-the-office-ribbon)